# Calling shared drive folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, iis, iis-7, shared-directory

I have two servers: A and B.
My Classic ASP application is deployed on Server A.
Server B contains a Folder (ScannedDocuments). I have created a Shared Drive on Server A to point to this folder. The Share Drive is named Q:.

On IE 7, when I try to access file using javascript, I am using:

```
window.open(file://Q:/a.txt)
```

It opens the file. But on IE 8 and above and all versions of Firefox, it is not opening. Neither an error is generated nor the file is opening.

I guess it is getting blocked by browser's security features.

Please let me know how I can open files on these browser versions.

Is there any other way to open a remote file using javascript or using IIS?

** Edited **
I tried creating a Virtual Directory on IIS and pointing to Shared Drive. But it gives error: resource or directory not found.

I am using IIS 7

Comment: Share a File using web server  Sharing file via network is not good idea..

Comment: @AnantDabhi You mean IIS? What steps I need to follow? I am using IIS 7. I tried creating virtual directory on IIS and pointing it to shared drive. When I use: window.open(https://ip address/Q/a.txt it is giving resource not found.

Comment: yes you are going right way .. Check this url  https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/article.html?id=309  it might be helpful to  you

Comment: @AnantDabhi Thanks. I will try and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

@Anant Dabhi is right - create simple Ajax call to server ant return file content.

Client (JS). Use it instead of window.open(file://Q:/a.txt)

```
function getFile(filename) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/YourWeb/File/Get",
        data: {
            filename: filename
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Your "backend". Assume that your are using .NET :)

```
public ActionResult Get()
{
    string pathToFolder = "x:\\yyy\\zzz";
    // Strip any directories and leave only name of file. Exception is possible ;)
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request["filename"]);
    byte[] ba = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(pathToFolder, filename));
    string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ba);

    // Return as text (if you are absolutetlly sure it is text!)
    return Content(s);
    // Or pack it in JSON object to have status
    return Json(new { Status = true, Data = s });
}
```

You could connect to UNC if you wish https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It is a classic ASP application.

Comment: I think, it's ok to use this code in ASP.NET. But you need to return JSON object, using `new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { Status = true, Data = s });`